# Add (xml) file to a .xlsx file and keep after 'save as'

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx

Hi I have a need to store some data in a excel file (.xlsx) so I can send the file to our customers and extract data from it again later when they send us the file back to update some content.

The customer should not be able to see the data we store in the file, and certainly not be able to remove it (accidentally). In fact he should not be aware of it in any way. Also we want to add this info from a service on a system that doesn't have Excel installed.

I know that a .xlsx file is basicaly a zip file so I can extract the data and add a file to it, zip it again and have a valid file that can be opened by Excel. Only problem here is that after saving that file in Excel my custom xml file is removed from the package. So I need to know how to fix this.

What I have:

```
XNamespace MyNamespace = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
XNamespace ExcelNamespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships";
string ExtractionPath = @"C:\temp\test\";
string ExcelFile = @"C:\temp\example.xlsx";

Directory.CreateDirectory(ExtractionPath);
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(ExcelFile, ExtractionPath);

var Root = new XElement(MyNamespace + "tracker",
    new XAttribute("version", "1.0.0.1"),
    new XElement("connections"));

var file = Path.Combine(ExtractionPath, "connectioninfo.xml");
if (!File.Exists(file))
{
    var relsPath = Path.Combine(ExtractionPath, "_rels", ".rels");
    var rels = XElement.Load(relsPath);
    rels.Add(new XElement(ExcelNamespace + "Relationship",
        new XAttribute("Id", "XXXX"),
        new XAttribute("Type", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/customXml"),
        new XAttribute("Target", "connectioninfo.xml")));
    rels.Save(relsPath);
}
Root.Save(file);

if (File.Exists(ExcelFile)) File.Delete(ExcelFile);
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(ExtractionPath, ExcelFile, System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.NoCompression, false);
```

When I run this code I end up with a file that contains my connectioninfo.xml file and that I can open in Excel. But when I save that file in excel and unzip the package again, then the connectioninfo.xml file is gone.

So question -> what am I missing to keep the file in the package after saving?

---

PS: I have also tried following code, but same problem ...
(using System.IO.Packaging;)

```
using (Package package = Package.Open(ExcelFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    Uri uriPartTarget = new Uri("/customXml/example.xml", UriKind.Relative);

    if (!package.PartExists(uriPartTarget))
    {
        PackagePart customXml = package.CreatePart(uriPartTarget,
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.customXmlProperties+xml");

        using (Stream partStream = customXml.GetStream(FileMode.Create,
            FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            var doc = new XElement("test", new XElement("content","Hello world!"));
            doc.Save(partStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So... you have added content to the compressed file that Excel does not know about. Then, you want Excel to preserve that content when it saves the file again, which it does from the content of the spreadsheet in memory. How would you expect Excel to do that?

Comment: Because of the relation I have added. It is possible to store custom xml in a xlsx file. That can be used by plugins etcetera. And even if not, I would expect that excel also extracts the package, edits the files and then compresses everything back when the user saves. In fact I think it's harder to remove the file then to keep it ...